# WCF and Windows 10 Targeted PCL

Tags: c#, wcf, portable-class-library, windows-10

I have a VS 2015 solution where one project is a WPF application that is hosting a WCF service. The second one is a Windows 10 UWP project that is a client and is consuming the service.

I'd like to place my service contract (shared interface) in a Windows 10 (.NET 4.6) targeted Portable Class Library, but with this setup the ServiceContractAttribute is not recognized. I have to retarget to Windows 8.1 to be allowed to use these attributes. But such a library won't be usable in both projects.

How can I share my service interface between those two projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as sharing the interface for a WCF service goes, I discovered targeting Windows 8.1 / .NET 4.5.1 PCL is working for both projects, so I guess I can stick with this solution.

I don't know if there are some downsides in not targeting Windows 10 directly, but I will see eventually.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on the project
- Properties
- Select 'Library'
- Targeting: click Change...
- Select only .NET Framework 4.5.1 and Windows 8.1

Targeting Windows 10 and .NET Framework 4.6 doesn't work.